# Django ForeignKey create

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to assign many Region to the UserProfile model, how to do it?

the code

```
class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

 class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(

    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Then it is *not* a `ForeignKey`, but a `ManyToManyField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation you describe is *not* a `ForeignKey`, which means that a `UserProfile` has (at most) *one* related `Region`, but a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField).

A `ManyToManyField` thus means that a region can be related to zero, one, or more `UserProfile`s, and a `UserProfile` can be related to zero, one, or more `Region`s.

You can thus change the models to:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

 class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region)
```

In a relational database this is implemented by adding an extra (hidden) table with `ForeignKey`s to `Region`s and `UserProfile`s. But the Django ORM works in a "transparant" way and thus hides the implementation details.

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) for more information on how to "populate" such relation.

Answer (score 1):

`from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser`

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region,related_name='User')
```

I think this is the ideal way to implement what you need. Using ManyToManyField allows you to map userprofile object to more than one region object and vice versa.

Also, Inheriting Abstract User allows you to add region field to Django User Table, which is better than creating another table for linking user to  and region field.